# how to use ajax in custom page and post in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have created a custom pages whit country and city dropdown. I want to use ajax to select city to according to the country selection.
I tried to add ajax call directly in my page but it doesnt work

I dont know how to fix it.

Please help me, your help will appreciated heartly.

my link is as under
[my site](http://test.inextrix.com/ITPLA2B_p)

Comment: Where i Find country and city dropdown in your site

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [wp_ajax_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) hook in order to use ajax in your pages.

```
<?php 

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );

    function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
        // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response
    }
?>
<script>

    jQuery.post(
        '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>', 
        {
            'action': 'add_foobar',
            'data':   'foobarid'
        }, 
        function(response){
            alert('The server responded: ' + response);
        }
    );
    </script>
```

Comment: thankX for reply dear.
But my page is custom and I created HTML inside that page. So how can I achieve ajax call. Plz give me in detail ans as I am new in wordpress.